# How can I insert a string containing special characters into a file on a remote server, after a match in that file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, special-characters

I have a string containing tabs and newlines that I need to insert at a specific place (after a match) in a file on a remote server.

I know how I can get the string into a remote file:

```
me@local$ grep string file | ssh remote "cat > otherfile"
me@remote$ cat otherfile
string:foo
string:bar
```

However, I want to insert the result from `grep` after a specific match in `otherfile`. Locally, I can do that by saving the `grep` result and then quoting everything like a mad-man inside a `sed` command:

```
me@local$ foo="$(grep string file)"
me@local$ sed -i "/^### MATCH ###/ a "${foo}"" otherfile
me@local$ cat otherfile
### MATCH ###
string:foo
string:bar
```

I struggle with the last step, inserting the `grep` result remotely after the match. Neither of these solutions work, unfortunately:

```
me@local$ foo="$(grep string file)"
me@local$ ssh remote sed -i "/^### MATCH ###/ a "${foo}"" otherfile
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated address regex
me@local$ grep string file | ssh remote "cat | sed -i \"/^### MATCH ###/ a\\\" otherfile"
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**Edit** I have made some progress by more quote-magic, but newlines don't seem to transfer nicely:

```
me@local$ foo="$(grep string file)"
me@local$ ssh remote sed -i \"/^###\ MATCH\ ###/ a \'${foo}\'\" otherfile
me@remote$ cat otherfile
### MATCH ###
'string:foo string:bar'
```

More quote-magic doesn't really solve it yet:

```
me@local$ foo="$(grep string file)"
me@local$ ssh remote sed -i \"/^###\ MATCH\ ###/ a ${foo}\" otherfile
me@remote$ cat otherfile
### MATCH ###
string:foo string:bar
```

**Possible solution edit**: I have an excessively ugly workaround using `printf`:

```
tmp=$(printf "%q" "$(grep string file)")
# because printf may add $'' around the string
[ "${tmp:0:2}" = "$'" ] && tmp="${tmp:2}" && tmp="${tmp%?}"
ssh remote "sed -i \"/^### MATCH ###/ a ${tmp}\" otherfile" < /dev/null
```

But I find that so repulsive I'm not adding it as an answer in the hope that someone else replies with a slightly more elegant way.

Comment: "# because printf may add $'' around the string". Are you testing with shell debug/trace, `set -vx`? What you describe sounds like a debugging artifact of std_err output. Unless you're redirecting std_err output to std_out, while using `set -vx`, I think once you turn off debugging by hiding the `set -vx`, or using `set +vx`, you'll find that the `$'...'` extra stuff has gone away, and you really have clean strings. Good luck.

Comment: Also, (I don't have a way to test right now), did you try `ssh remote -c 'sed ......'` ? Also, you can get your variable values, but keep string together with concatenations like `sed -k "/^### MATCH ###/ a "'"${foo}"'" otherfile`. It does get hairy, as you see.  That workaround would look pretty good to me, vs faced with no solution:-) +1 for well defined small test cases illustrating your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid escaping bugs is not to escape at all.
Since `sed` supports reading the command string from a file, you need to make it read from stdin, as in your first example.

```
me@local$ foo="$(grep string file)"
me@local$ sedcmd="/^### MATCH ###/ a "${foo}""
me@local$ echo "$sedcmd" | ssh remote sed -f /dev/stdin otherfile
```

If your system doesn't have /dev/stdin, try `/dev/fd/0`.